# In Swift 2.2, how to consolidate the for-loop statement?

Tags: swift, swift2

In Swift 2.2, C-style for statement is deprecated, so I modify following for-loop:

```
for var idx=data.count-1; idx>=0; --idx
```

into

```
for idx in (0...data.count-1).reverse()  // <--- new statement
```

However, I found, when `data.count` is 0 during execution, the new statement will crash with error `fatal error: Can't form range with end < start`.

Is there a best/standard way to code for this case?

P.S. I think I have to use different kinds of loops/syntax to replace my unified C-style loops. Any further comment or suggestion on this is welcome.

Comment: Your for(;;) and for-in loops aren't the same: first one loops from data.count-1 to 1 and second one loops from data.count-1 to 0.

Comment: @Valentin thanks, I have modified it. It wasn't meant to be different.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated my answer with stride(through:by:) instead of stride(to:by:), you may want to accept it if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`Strideable.stride(through:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Strideable_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/Strideable/s:FEsPs10Strideable6strideFT7throughx2bywx6Stride_GVs13StrideThroughx_) to generate your for-loop range, like this:

```
for idx in (data.count-1).stride(through: 0, by: -1) {
    print(idx)
}
```

It works even if `data.count == 0`.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a range as

```
0 ... data.count-1
```

terminates with a runtime exception if `data.count` is zero. It is 
often better to use the `..<` operator to make a range that
omits its upper value, in your case:

```
0 ..< data.count
```

This works for `data.count == 0` as well and creates an empty
range in that case. This applies to
both forward and backward iteration:

```
for idx in 0 ..< data.count { ... }
for idx in (0 ..< data.count).reverse() { ... }
```

(Of course `stride()` is a sensible alternative for the second case.)

Answer (score 2):

In such a simple loop, there is no need for arithmetic operations.

If `data` is an array, use `indices`:

```
for index in data.indices {
}

for index in data.indices.reverse() {
}
```

or access the data directly

```
for item in data {
}

for item in data.reverse() {
}
```

or a combination of the previous using `enumerate`

```
for (index, item) in data.enumerate() {
}
```

Note that all `for-in` loops above can be also written as `forEach`:

```
data.indices.forEach {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead, use `for idx in (0..<data.count).reverse()`. This will form the empty range that you want when `data.count == 0`.